# Android Concurrency issue

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have strictly separated the layers between different parts of my Android application. 
At some point of execution I am updating my data from xml service on Internet. That updating takes up about 10 seconds and is done completely in the background - meaning the user interface of an application works fine. However further calls to my class (later - DataManager) which is responsible for data updating (after update has been started but not yet finished) makes my application crash. NullPointerException is thrown with objects which NEVER are null.

So I assume that only one Thread can use my DataManager at one time and calls to DataManager from other threads ends up in exceptions.

I tried various combinations of putting 'synchronized' keywords near sensitive methods but it seems that when update is executing - NOTHING can use ANYTHING from my DataManager.

BTW other classes which are related to DataManager during the execution also seem to hold null objects.

I guess I am just missing some kind of design pattern which is used to deal with concurrency problems and maybe anyone can suggest me something?

Comment: Could you offer some code you feel is the root cause of the NullPointerException.  It's hard to get an idea of any concurrency issue.

Comment: See if it was just a one NullPointerException then I could handle it myself, I am quite experienced with debugging Android apps. But this issue seems to affect whole application. Sadly I cannot provide the code because there's too much of it affected and the code base is quite big... It's not like I forgot to initialize some stupid variables... Everything works perfectly fine when I am not updating.  And update actually touches only four ArrayLists in my manager class. Actually wait a sec, I can post my update method and explain it a bit.

Comment: So this is the actual method which does all the updating: http://pastebin.com/gY3x8wiq
It has direct (and indirect) access only to four mentioned ArrayLists. Even though during this execution other objects are also affected.

Comment: Is the NPE on the ArrayLists?

Comment: Forget about it, Daniel's answer got me on the right track of how such concurrent tasks should be implemented. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble dealing with using the Apache http client because of threading issues and I think your issue could be similar in that respect.  What I ended up doing was setting up a callback scheme.  This may or may not work for you, of course.

This may seem a bit Rube Goldberg-like to you, but it worked for me.

I would have my UI thread call my data manager object with a method that spawned a thread to go and acquire the data.  The method's return value is an object that would EVENTUALLY have the data in it.  I would have my activity extend an interface, something like "DataCallbackInterface", with a method that the thread would call after it acquired the data (i.e. the last line in run()).  Since that call will inherently be within another thread, you'll need to use a Handler to run anything useful in your implementation of the DataCallbackInterface method.  When that method is called, you will know for a fact that the data is there and not rely on any strange synchronization flags to get it right.

Comment: That's actually a brilliant idea. Using events locks my DataManager inside the same thread which is executing update and disallow other program parts from using DataManager correctly! Right? :D
So I should make such background task which executes everything and returns data only as it's last line of code. So during execution my program would work with old data in DataManager and after update execution is complete, the data would be replaced. And no worries with threads! Right? I mean, did I got this idea correctly?

Comment: I think I did. Although it will require to redesign some of my application parts, but that definitely will work! Thank you :)